# Contradiction - Equivalence of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I think I'm having a brain fart. Please tell me if my reasoning is correct.

Suppose you have a polynomial-function $f(x)$ of degree $N$ that has coefficients $a_{0 \leq j \leq N}$ and roots $r_{0 \leq j \leq N}$. Then suppose you have a different function $g(x)$ that has coefficients $b_{0 \leq j \leq N}$ but, coincidentally, the same roots $r_{0 \leq j \leq N}$.

Now if you were to factor both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ knowing their roots, you would get the following:

$$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{N}a_jx^j=\prod_{j=0}^{N}(x-r_j)$$

$$g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{N}b_jx^j=\prod_{j=0}^{N}(x-r_j)$$

But then according to the right-most equation for both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, $f(x)=g(x)$, but we know that that isn't necessarily the case. What is the error?

My guess at the error is that in order to factor properly, you must make the polynomial's leading coefficient equal to 1. If you were to multiply out all of the $(x-r_j)$ terms, the leading coefficient would be 1. Therefore, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ should actually be

$$f(x) = a_N\prod_{j=0}^{N}(x-r_j)$$

$$g(x) = b_N\prod_{j=0}^{N}(x-r_j)$$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, without factoring, $\frac{f}{g}$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant by Liouville's theorem.